# Python: NameError while using nested classes

Tags: python

I encountered with the following error:

```
NameError: name 'JsonCleaner' is not defined
```

The line, causing the error is the first pair in dictionary `ERROR_CODES_MAPPING_DICT` (see code below):

```
from sshop.engine.models import WrongJsonError

class JsonCleaner:


    class NormalizeError(Exception):

        ERROR_NO_CODE = 0
        ERROR_TYPE_MISMATCH = 1
        ERROR_WRONG_VALUE = 2
        ERROR_LACK_OF_FIELD = 3

        def __init__(self, error_desc, error_code=ERROR_NO_CODE):
            self.error_desc = error_desc
            self.error_code = error_code

        def __unicode__(self):
            return repr(self.error_desc)


    # .... some methods ........


    ERROR_CODES_MAPPING_DICT = {
        # Line where exception is raised:
        JsonCleaner.NormalizeError.ERROR_NO_CODE:       WrongJsonError.NO_ERROR, 
        JsonCleaner.NormalizeError.ERROR_LACK_OF_FIELD: WrongJsonError.ERROR_LACK_OF_FIELD,
        JsonCleaner.NormalizeError.ERROR_TYPE_MISMATCH: WrongJsonError.ERROR_TYPE_MISMATCH,
        JsonCleaner.NormalizeError.ERROR_WRONG_VALUE:   WrongJsonError.ERROR_WRONG_VALUE, 
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class name cannot be used within the class scope since the name isn't actually bound until the class is completely defined. Move the dict literal outside the class scope.

```
JsonCleaner.ERROR_CODES_MAPPING_DICT = ...
```

Answer (score 3):

JsonCleaner ist not completely defined at that point and therefor unknown. Just remove it and use NormalizeError.ERROR_NO_CODE and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing "JsonCleaner" with "self".

```
 ERROR_CODES_MAPPING_DICT = {
    # Line where exception is raised:
    self.NormalizeError.ERROR_NO_CODE:       WrongJsonError.NO_ERROR, 
    self.NormalizeError.ERROR_LACK_OF_FIELD: WrongJsonError.ERROR_LACK_OF_FIELD,
    self.NormalizeError.ERROR_TYPE_MISMATCH: WrongJsonError.ERROR_TYPE_MISMATCH,
    self.NormalizeError.ERROR_WRONG_VALUE:   WrongJsonError.ERROR_WRONG_VALUE, 
}
```

Comment: `self` doesn't exist either; it only exists within a method since it's passed as one of the arguments.